# How can I change the ruby to use?

Tags: ruby

Im using this version of ruby when I compile with compass:

```
/home/tirengarfio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/
```

How can I use the version in `/usr/local/lib`?

My `$PATH` is `/usr/local/lib:sr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @Severin I  don't know, how to know it? Sorry, Im not a ruby programmer but HTML/CSS/LAMP programmer

Comment: Fire `which rvm` to see if you are using `RVM`..

Comment: type in console `rmv -v ` or `rbenv -v` and you will see.

Comment: RVM (Ruby Version Manager) is the extact right tool for you if you have multiple versions of Ruby installed on your system.

Comment: @ArupRakshit no output

Comment: @ziiweb That means `RVM` is not installed, then how that path `/home/tirengarfio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ ` you got..

Comment: @ArupRakshit sorry, I modified the $PATH

Comment: @ArupRakshit when I run rvm -v I get `Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/tirengarfio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247'.

rvm 1.22.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]` This is my $PATH: http://pastebin.com/d76KUBZZ

Comment: `sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.0` if not uses [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use RVM (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to handle multiple versions of Ruby on the same system. You can set the default by using the following command:

```
rvm --default use 2.0.0-p247
```

The version defined after "use" can of course be anything you have installed on your system.